# Updating an object after passing it into multiple functions

Tags: python, pyqt

I am creating an instance of an object, passing it into another object, and then passing it into yet another object like this:

```
person = Person(fname, lname)
info = Information(person)
summary = Summary(person)

qt_stack_widget.add_child(info)
qt_stack_widget.add_child(summary)

qt_stack_widget.start()
qt_stack_widget.show()
```

In the `Information` object, it will collect information with user input then use the `person` object's mutators to add information to that object.

In `Summary`, it will take the `person` object then collect some more information from it and like before mutate the object further.

But the mutations performed in `Information` on the `person` object is not reflected in the `person` object in `Summary`.

Does anyone know why this would be?

I know that the changes are not reflected because I am sending the initial empty object `person` to `info` and `summary`, but how can I make the `person` object in `summary` update after the changes in `information`?

The program works like this:

1. the user launches the program
2. the user enters information which is then mutated into `person`
3. the user clicks next to go to the next page of the applet
4. the page displays the information entered in the previous page

So basically once the `person` object is updated in `Information`, the changes are not reflected in the `person` object that was sent to `Summary`, even though it's the same object.

What I'm asking is, how can I get the `person` object to reflect the changes in `Summary` that was done in `Information`?

Main:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import sys
import root_ui
import Individual

import views.launch
import basic_info


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    root = root_ui.RootUI()

    individual = Individual.Individual()

    splash = views.launch.Splash(root.next)
    info = basic_info.Information(individual, root.next)
    summary = views.more_info.Summary(individual, root.next)

    root.add_child(splash)
    root.add_child(info)
    root.add_child(summary)

    root.start()
    root.show()

    app.processEvents()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


main()
```

Information

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class Information(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, individual, rt):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setLayout(self.build(individual, rt))
        self.setFixedHeight(200)

    def firstname(self):
        fname_box = QHBoxLayout()
        fname_label = QLabel("What's your first name?")
        self.__fname_input = QLineEdit()
        fname_box.addStretch(1)
        fname_box.addWidget(fname_label)
        fname_box.addStretch(2)
        fname_box.addWidget(self.__fname_input)

        return fname_box

    def lastname(self):
        lname_box = QHBoxLayout()
        lname_label = QLabel("What's your last name?")
        self.__lname_input = QLineEdit()
        lname_box.addStretch(1)
        lname_box.addWidget(lname_label)
        lname_box.addStretch(2)
        lname_box.addWidget(self.__lname_input)

        return lname_box

    def build(self, individual, rt):
        note = QLabel("Let's start off with some basic information.")

        submit = QPushButton()
        submit.setText("Next!")
        submit.clicked.connect(lambda: self.next_op(individual, rt))

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addStretch(1)
        vbox.addWidget(note)
        vbox.addStretch(2)
        vbox.addLayout(self.firstname())
        vbox.addStretch(3)
        vbox.addLayout(self.lastname())
        vbox.addStretch(4)
        vbox.addWidget(submit)

        return vbox

    def next_op(self, individual, rt):
        if self.__fname_input.text() != "" or self.__lname_input.text() != "":
            individual.firstname = self.__fname_input.text()
            individual.lastname = self.__lname_input.text()
            rt()
```

Summary:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class Summary(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, individual, rt):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setLayout(self.build(individual, rt))
        note = QLabel("This is what you have so far:")
        fname = QLabel("First name = {}".format(individual.firstname))
        lname = QLabel("First name = {}".format(individual.lastname))
        
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addStretch(1)
        vbox.addWidget(note)
        vbox.addStretch(2)
        vbox.addWidget(fname)
        vbox.addStretch(3)
        vbox.addWidget(lname)

        return vbox
```

Individual:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3


class Individual:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__first_name = ""
        self.__last_name = ""

    @property
    def firstname(self):
        return self.__first_name

    @firstname.setter
    def firstname(self, fname):
        self.__first_name = fname

    @property
    def lastname(self):
        return self.__last_name

    @lastname.setter
    def lastname(self, lname):
        self.__last_name = lname

    def __str__(self):
        return "First name: {}, Last name: {}".format(self.firstname, self.lastname)
```

Comment: If you're actually mutating the object, it should do what you expect. So the only explanation is it's not really mutating the object. Without seeing all the relevant code, there's no way to know what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @Barmar I've added more detail, can you check again please?

Comment: Don't describe what the program is doing, show the actual code. The description is what you expect it to do, but you've obviously made a mistake in the implementation.

Comment: You need to post a [mcve].

Comment: Well, there are two separate questions here.  One is "how can I get the object to update", and I think that's already happening.  The other is "how can I get the UI elements to display the updated info?"   Is that your real issue?

Comment: @TimRoberts I can display the UI elements fine. The problem is that the object being sent to `summary` isn't displaying the updates

Comment: @Barmar added code

Comment: Don't post code as links, put it in the question.

Comment: `Information` doesn't modify `individual` until the user clicks on the submit button. I suspect you're looking at it before that happens.

Comment: After you change the object, you somehow need to notify the Summary object to update the QLabels with the new info.  That won't happen automatically.

Comment: @Barmar how so? it is updating in `next_op()` ?

Comment: But you call `next_op()` from `submit.clicked.connect(lambda: self.next_op(individual, rt))` which is run when the submit button is clicked.

Comment: @Barmar yes, the submit button will trigger the updating of the `individual` object.

but on the next page, shouldn't the `individual` object reflect those changes?

Comment: Where is `Summary` displaying the updated attributes of `individual`?

Comment: You're creating the `Summary` object before they go to the next page. And it copies the initial values of `individual.firstname` and `individual.lastname` into the labels. As @TimRoberts said, you need to update those labels when `individual` is modified.

Comment: @Barmar right here: `fname = QLabel("First name = {}".format(individual.firstname))` `lname = QLabel("First name = {}".format(individual.lastname))`

Comment: That's not the updated attributes, that's the attributes before the user has submitted.

Comment: @Barmar Do you have any suggestions on how to do that? Like a listener or something?

Comment: As an aside, remove the pointless properties from `Individual` and just use a regular attribute. The *whole point* of `property` is **not** to write boilerplate getters and setters

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga do you mean the empty initializaroonss in the `Individual` constructor? I thought it would be best practice to set it to an empty state instead of a garbage value. Also, if I use the `property` do I still need to declare the class's data members in the constructor?

Comment: @yparam98 no, I mean **don't use `property`** in this situation. You class should have *two methods*, `__init__` and `__str__`, remove the property getters/setters, and just use `self.firstname = ''` and `self.lastname = ''` in `__init__`. You *don't need those properties, they serve no purpose*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the `Summary` first, and pass it to `Information`. Then `next_op()` can notify `Summary` to update its labels.

```
class Information(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, individual, rt, summary):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setLayout(self.build(individual, rt))
        self.setFixedHeight(200)
        self.summary = summary

    ...

    def next_op(self, individual, rt):
        if self.__fname_input.text() != "" or self.__lname_input.text() != "":
            individual.firstname = self.__fname_input.text()
            individual.lastname = self.__lname_input.text()
            self.summary.update_labels(individual)
            rt()
```

```
class Summary:
    def __init__(self, individual, rt):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setLayout(self.build(individual, rt))
        note = QLabel("This is what you have so far:")
        self.fname = QLabel("First name = {}".format(individual.firstname))
        self.lname = QLabel("Last name = {}".format(individual.lastname))
        
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addStretch(1)
        vbox.addWidget(note)
        vbox.addStretch(2)
        vbox.addWidget(self.fname)
        vbox.addStretch(3)
        vbox.addWidget(self.lname)

        return vbox

    def update_labels(self, individual):
        self.fname.setText("First name = {}".format(individual.firstname))
        self.lname.setText("Last name = {}".format(individual.lastname))
```